# Julia: is there a function to obtain the version number of a package?

Tags: julia

I see that `Pkg.status("PkgName")` prints something like this `Pkg v0.12.0` to the REPL.

I tried to `@edit Pkg.status("Pkgname")` but encountered some macro code that I don't understand.

What's the easiest way to obtain the version number of a package in the current activate environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can use `Pkg.dependencies()` to get all information about all packages, as it was discussed [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-use-pkg-dependencies-instead-of-pkg-installed/36416). For example

```
using Pkg

julia> filter(x-> x.second.name == "Crayons", Pkg.dependencies()) |> x -> first(x)[2].version   
v"4.0.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

`Pkg.installed()` does give you the version of all installed packages as version strings, but it is deprecated and is likely to be removed in future versions of julia

```
julia> Pkg.installed()
┌ Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated
└ @ Pkg ~/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Pkg.jl:561
Dict{String,VersionNumber} with 81 entries:
  "Interact"                    => v"0.10.3"
  "ForwardDiff"                 => v"0.10.12"
  "UMAP"                        => v"0.1.6"
  "Juno"                        => v"0.8.2"
```

Comment: What's the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to use the widely-used `Compat.jl` package.  It has a `pkgversion` function:

```
using Compat
using PkgName

pkgversion(PkgName)
```